# Generated One extra blank log file For one Application Run

Tags: java, logging, logback, logback-classic, spring-logback

I am Configured Logger For my application And Give the Logfilename as Current Time Stamp So It Expected to create one log File with the name as current Time stamp BuT INSTEDE IT CREATE ONE LOGFILE WITH CURRENT TIMESTAMP AND ANOTHER FILE WHICH IS BLANK CANT FIGURE OUT WHY IT CREATING EXTRA FILE??

I am using Logback logger in my application and Here is my logback.xml looks like My application is simple core java application. where i user logger to log the statements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>`enter code here`

 <timestamp key="byDay" datePattern="yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'''AT'''HH'-'mm'-'ss"/>


   <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
      <file> Myapplication${byDay}.txt </file>
      <append>FALSE</append>
      <encoder>
         <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>

   <root level="DEBUG">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE" />

   </root>
  </configuration>
```